# Bitbucket Pipelines randomly fail - "couldn't clone the repository" error

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Occasionally Bitbucket pipelines fail for no apparent reason. It usually happens on feature or hotfix branches (for now it never happened on master, but that's maybe just statistics).

Rerunning multiple times doesn't help.

The newest code that is on those branches doesn't touch `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file which works fine on other branches and master.

The error returned is:

> We hit a glitch and couldn't clone the repository. Please rerun the
>   pipeline. See our documentation
>
> View bitbucket-pipelines.yml

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Just tried the dumbest thing. **Pushed an empty commit** to trigger pipelines and it works:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "trigger pipelines"
```

I guess that any commit will do, but I had no reason to modify my code ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. For me, I was actually triggering a custom pipeline on a specific commit, that I had since rebased. After supplying the correct commit hash, I was back in business.